# How to alternate between several templates in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

My meteor app has a base.html file like this:

```
<head>
  <title>MyApp</title>
</head>

<body>
    <template name="bodyContent">
        {{subContent}}
    </template>
</body>
```

Next, I define three different templates:

```
<template name="templateA">Some text</template>
<template name="templateB">Bla bla bla</template>
<template name="templateC">Your highscore is {{score}}</template>
```

**How can I make {{subContent}} so it is able to alternate between one of these three templates at runtime?**

Something like:

```
currentTemplateUsed = 'templateB'

Template.bodyContent.subContent = Template[currentTemplateUsed]
```

But that doesn't work. Are there other approaches to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [meteor router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router), it is able to dynamically change templates. Possible downside is that it can only change ***one*** template at a time.

Alternatively, there's a bit of info on Meteor's Handlebars:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Handlebars

Basically, you have to use the template as a function, and pass data to it in order for Handlebars to parse it, like this:

```
var currentTemplateUsed = 'templateC';

var data = {
   score : 12
}

Template.bodyContent.subContent = Template[currentTemplateUsed](data);
```

Returns `Your highscore is 12`

Answer (score 0):

Templates inside of `<body> ... </body>` don't seem to work, I couldn't pass data inside. I might be wrong, but I had to put it outside and use:

```
<body>
  {{> body_content}}
</body>
```